# make install on Windows in specified directory

Tags: makefile

How to change directory where `make install` installs library that i'm building?

I tried `DESTDIR` option but it creates folder `Program Files (x86)` in this directory but I don't need it. I need to install library to exactly my directory (for example, `C:/Users/USER/my_project/lib/`, **NOT** to `C:/Users/USER/my_project/lib/Program Files (x86)/`)

Comment: What library are you building? Each library can do whatever it wants in `make install`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat currently https://github.com/ArthurSonzogni/FTXUI

Comment: So you're running CMake? Try `-DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=...`.